# Xamarin Seprate UI design with common code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Im new to Xamarin but I worked on Xamarin.forms where I design common UI for both Android and iOS and wrote common code to interact with the UI. But my doubt is how can I create different UI for both Android in graphical designer and for iOS in Storyboard and write common code to connect with both the UI's in Xamarin.forms.

To be clear when we create a Xamarin.form project it creates basically 3 projects one is shared and 2 are for Android and iOS. So in Android and iOS projects I want to desing the UI and write the common Interaction code in shared project for both.

Comment: Find the free book about Xamarin.Forms from Xamarin and it contain the details on how to use platform dependent UI in a Xamarin.Forms solution.

Comment: Use MvvmCross, it provides exactly what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Those articles helped me a lot in understanding of Xamarin Native development:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Xamarin.iOS-UI-project

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Xamarin.Android-UI-project